# Compiling my App gives no errors but hangs when compiling on device

Tags: iphone, xcode, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I've made an iPad App. I was able to run this App on my device and on simulator.

After I've updated several classes (which I tested in simulator) I wasn't able to run my App on my device. It gives no errors but just hangs when compiling.

I'm thinking it's something with a class which came out very large and has some mathematical functions inside (calculations of transforms etc.)

After a long runtime Xcode gives back this error (something about a 'clang error'):
[image]

Anyone has any experience with these kind of issues and could find a solution?

EDIT:

Within my viewdidload method i have set 112 float values (i.e. value = 12;) and save them (with NSUSerdefaults).

Only setting these values solved my problem. No idea why this was giving me compile errors. I'm thinking the mathematical functions (after setting the float values) took to much memory or CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cleaning your build and rebuild again?

Menu > Product > Clean

Comment: Cleaning my project/ deleting my project from my iPad or restarting XCode did not fixed my issue. I'm going to check if NSZombie can help me out. Any other suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

close & reopen XCode, "Clean All Targets" then rebuild. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project, delete the app from you iPad and try again. Should work.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to "Build and Analyze" or an ad-hoc build or debug build?

If your code crashed because of any memory issues or bad access memory due to any infinite loop, try to enable NSZombieEnabled in your executable settings. It will point you to the code snippet where the code crashes.

To enable "NSZombieEnabled", go to

**Edit Active Executables -> Arguments -> Variables in the environment -> Add name as "NSZombieEnabled" and value to "YES"**

Hopes this helps.

Comment: I did enabled zombies within my schems. However I can't build my App. So I think I can't use zombies at this point.

Comment: which compiler are you using to build the app? you can use LLVM/Clang static analyzer. Take a look at this post to know more about using llvm in iphone. http://www.neat.io/posts/2009/01/06/using-the-llvm-clang-static-analyzer-for-iphone-apps.html

Comment: I tried both (Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0 & LLVM GCC 4.2) unfortunately still no succes